# Timestamp, Date, Time, or DateTime which is which?

Tags: php, mysql

I know that this is longed asked question but still I can't find an answer.

I have a fix time in and out in my database.
   Also I have date_in and date_out in separate columns.
  All the data in my database come from csv which is in that exact format.
  Can I concatenate (time_in and date_in) and (time_out and date_out) and put them in a designated column which is in timestamp format?

I'm making a import and export of csv in which those info below is concern. So far I can export it but 
my import doesn't work well. I use the phpmyadmin csv load data to import. Can't get my head in importation of dates and times coz other data mess up in my database.

> Note: total_hrs is not included in the csv which means that it is already in my database. And it doesn't have a value so basicaly I will provide values for that in my script.

Example:

```
id | time_in | time_out |   date_in   |   date_out  |  total_hrs
 1 | 9:30pm  | 7:30am   | 2013-12-01  |  2013-13-01 |     ?

This should have a 10 hours elapsed time.
```

So basically it also has a different date. 
    I'm confused whether I need to convert the time in timestamps or something similar to get the time difference or I also need to have the date as well to be a basis in getting the difference between the two time??Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be also 34, 58,.. hours. I advise you to store timestamps, if you will need pretty display of it you can just use print (or smth similiar) function in MySql.

Comment: Your right about that. In my database I store those hours as time type not timestamps so I need to change that? so do I need to change that for convenience of getting the time diff.

Comment: @Jmilez look there: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html so yes you need to change to timestamp/datetime or add another column for date.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the date you should use timestamps. They're easier to compare.

Answer (score 0):

use timestamps in mysql:

```
INSERT INTO tblTimes (timein) VALUES (NOW());
UPDATE tblTimes SET timeout = NOW() WHERE id=$someid;
```

to compare, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff